# tableview not returning more than two rows

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

I have a tableview inside a window. I am presenting it this way. Iit comes from the bottom of the screen with a little animation.

```
let heights: CGFloat = 100 //(each row is 50 height, we have two source = two rows thus 100)
let y = (window.frame.height)
let yfinal = y - heights
menuTableView.frame = CGRect(x: ((window.frame.width + 20) / 2) - (((window.frame.width) ) / 2)  , y: (window.frame.height), width: (window.frame.width) - 20, height: heights)

window.addSubview(menuTableView)
window.bringSubviewToFront(menuTableView)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    self.menuTableView.frame.origin.y = yfinal - 15
}
```

My table view frame is a little messed up, I couldn't get it work with a simpler solution. It should have more than two rows since i am returning an array count of 4.

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: Your links don't work. Are "CNN" and "Bloomberg" are the rows? If so, why don't you use an action sheet? https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/action-sheets/

Comment: I have an array. i want my table view to have a number of actions depending on the array cout.

Comment: @CharlesXavier You should use a `UIActionSheet` instead of your tableView. You just have to pass the actions and text, and `UIKit` will take care of the animation, rowheights, etc.

Comment: You have set the `height` statically to `100 (= 2rows)` set it to higher number and you will see more rows.

Comment: @CharlesXavier for future readers, please explain what you did that worked - it's perfectly fine to write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Mojtaba Hosseini suggested that i change the height of the table view to be more than 100 since i have set the row of my cells to 50. Thus it is only return two cells. so i did the following adjustment. Thank you.

```
let heights:CGFloat = CGFloat(50 * (sourcesarray.count))
```